# how to manage dynamics crm Solution Programmatically?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I want to create a windows Form App to do This :

- Create a new dynamics CRM solution Publisher.
- Create 5 Solution with this Publisher .
- I have two managed Solution in my SharePoint and I want to import it
  to dynamics CRM.

Can anyone tell me how much time I will need to achieve This.

I will be gratefully if you can give me some tips or links to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

i have to give you some bad news
Dynamics SRM has deprecated their API and so the only way currently to create and manage environment is through PowerShell.

here is a link to the modules you are going to need in order to create and manage you Dynamics CRM:

[Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-powershell)

[Microsoft.Xrm.Data.Powershell](https://github.com/seanmcne/Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell)

[Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.ConfigurationMigration](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.ConfigurationMigration/1.0.0.53)

the last one is a bit tricky so you are looking for the cmdlet - `Import-CrmDataFile`